# How to control mobile keyboard type?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, mobile

I'm tryting to popup the number keyboard on mobile with input password.
But with password type the alphabet keyboards pops up.So I tried input number and tel with style

```
-webkit-text-security':'disc'
```

It still pops up alphabet keyboard. Is there any other way to solve it?

Comment: you want to open numeric keyboard from native android programming or by  using javascript language.

Comment: i want to open it by using javascript.